# Is it possible to find the equation of motion of a spring-mass system using differential equations as input?

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, system

I am searching for a solution the check the validity of my calculations on standard dynamics problems. Basic mechanical engineering environment, systems containing movable masses connected to each other by elements, ropes, springs, dampers, etc.

The definition of the impulse and momentum equations for each mass-element plus manually solving the resulting equation system leads me to the equation of motion, yaay! Plotting the result of the DSolve function is a great option, but is there any way in Mathematica to find the equation of motion using my impulse/momentum equations as an input?

For example my input:
{ m1 * x'' == F_a - d*x' - c*x ,
m2 * x'' == F_a - m2*g }

leads to the output:
(m1-m2)x'' + dx' + cx == m2*g

Is there any built in function for this? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less this

```
Eliminate[{m1 x''[t] == Fa - d x'[t] - c x[t], m2 x''[t] == Fa - m2 g}, Fa] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> g m2 + (-m1 + m2) x''[t] == c x[t] + d x'[t]
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly, but Eliminate also returns an extra condition like

`x'[t] + mK (r - R)^2 x''[t] && r != R`

Comment: @Mark It reminds you that under what condition the equation is true.

Comment: can I remove this && term? It causes an error using DSolve. I tried to declare a test variable with the result of the Eliminate function but without the && condition, DSolve works again.

Comment: @Mark You can extract what you want to feed into `DSolve`. Try `Part ([[...]])`.

Comment: Great solution, works fine! `Res = Eliminate[{...}]` and `Res = Res[[1]]` gives me the equation of motion, `DSolve` return no error with the global variables defined at the beginning of the notebook, `Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /.]` proves me the validity of the result! I am trying to make a `With` section for these variables (masses, spring constants, etc.) and run the same procedure. `DSolve` doesn't return any error, but the Plot is blank. Somehow `Res` doesn't appear in the `With` section, any ideas why? By manually declaring the EoM within the `With` section, `DSolve` and the plot runs fine

Comment: For those who have the same issue: use `Block` instead of `With`

Comment: @Mark If you have extra related issues, consider updating the post.